# Alias for external library type?

Tags: struct, library, data-types

Say you're importing a library, and that library contains a struct:

```
pragma solidity >=0.8.0;

library SomeLibrary {
    struct FooType {
        uint256 value;
    }
}

contract SomeContract {
    ...
}
```

I know that I can use that type as `SomeLibrary.FooType`. But that is verbose - it quickly ends up taking a lot of space in my implementation.

Is there any way I could set a local alias for this external library type? Ideally I would like to do this:

```
FooType = SomeLibrary.FooType;
```

Comment: Looks like there is an open issue about this: [Introduce a type definition keyword](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/1100).